# The Single Responsibility Principle and Event Listeners

Tags: java, swing, events, listeners

I'm currently trying to develop a simple GUI notepad to increase my skills in OOP.
I stick to the Single Responsibility Principle while developing.
I've divided the application into several parts following the principle.

```
// This class runs the whole application
public class Notepad {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                new NotepadFrame();
           }
            });

    }
}
// This class is responsible for setting up a frame
public class NotepadFrame extends JFrame {

public NotepadFrame() {
        super("Notepad");

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar.createMenuBar());

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
// This class sets up a menu bar
public class MenuBar {

public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        Buttons buttons = new Buttons();

        menuBar.add(buttons.createFileMenuItems());
        menuBar.add(buttons.createEditMenuItems());
        menuBar.add(buttons.createFormatMenuItems());
        menuBar.add(buttons.createHelpMenuItems());

        return menuBar;
    }
}
```

There are also the other classes. 
Buttons - this class is used to create the buttons of the menu bar.
MenuItemActionListeners - this class handles all of the events fired by the buttons.

Have I divided the application in a correct way according to the Simple Responsibility Principle?

I'd also like to find out the best ways to handle action listeners, mouse listeners etc.

So far, I have used one actionPerformed(SomeEvent e) method to handle all of the events.

```
private JButton button;
private JButton button2;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == button) {

    } else if (source == button2) {

    } // etc.

}
```

I realize this is the bad way of handling event listeners. As the application's size grows, adding so many conditional statements will make the code lest readable and the CPU performance will decrease.

How do you handle event listeners in your applications?
How would you write event listeners when developing huge and serious applications like MS Office or AutoCAD?

Answer (score 1):

I am very happy to see you want to use SRP while programming. The way you have done is perfectly acceptable. However, there is always a question on what level of these principles do you want to apply?

Also, in the code you provided (actionPerformed method), it is not OCP (Open Closed Principle) compliant and hence a bad design. Instead I would have separate methods for each type of event in each of those components that you have.

To keep the code DRY, you can have a method which tells you what to do when a component is selected. Delegate to this method from the several methods (due to different type of events) you associate for this component.

Hope this helps..

Comment: "If your application is doing several things and you have a very complex GUI, then it is not advisable to have separate classes for each of the components" ... do not agree at all. for a complex GUI or any complex system for that matter, its highly advisable to de-couple your classes and create components that interact with each other without knowing too much about the entire system.

Comment: Ravi Bhatt, I completely agree to what you say, and hence removed my statement. However, there is a limit on the extent you want to follow these principles..

Answer (score 1):

You are using one location where you handle all the events, which is a problem. In bigger applications you will handle events differently, different classes in your application will handle different events. Components listen to a few events only in which they are interested and not to all. For exmaple, a `undo event` makes sense to a `paragraph object` only and not to `File object`, a `save event` would make sense to the `menu object` and the `document object`.. etc.

Ideally, you classes would raise certain events and it will allow any other classes to subscribe to those events. Those subscribes are notified when an event occurs.

I would suggest you to look at the [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

See [*How to Use Actions*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which shows how [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) "can be used to separate functionality and state from a component." Charles Bell's [`HTMLDocumentEditor`](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276) is an example that shows how to reuse existing actions, as well as creating your own based on `AbstractAction`.